# SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values 00913. 00000 - "too many values"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from crew cr 
where cr.crew_supervisor_id in
(select *
from crew c
where not exists
(select crew_supervisor_id
from crew cr
where c.crew_id = cr.crew_supervisor_id))
order by crew_id;
```

so I'm trying to extract information out of a table i made, and sql developer keeps popping up this error, can anyone help me?? thanks a lot

Comment: You should specify a column name in IN subquery instead of just `*` - it means ALL fields. I guess it should be `c.crew_id`?

Comment: Yes, \* causes the syntax error. However I suppose that's not your only problem. What is the query supposed to return actually?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `select *` in the subquery.  A subquery used with `in` can only return one value.

```
select *
from crew cr 
where cr.crew_supervisor_id in (select crew_id
                                from crew c
                                where not exists (select crew_supervisor_id
                                                  from crew cr
                                                  where c.crew_id = cr.crew_supervisor_id
                                                 )
                               )
order by crew_id;
```

Comment: That's syntactically correct. However to ask "give me all records where the supervisor id is an existent crew id but not an existent supervisor id" will never return any record, right?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . I was trying to avoid understanding the query.  I really can't follow nested `exists`/`in` constructs, makes my head explode.  There are undoubtedly other ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the IN condition requires that you specify a column name in the sub-query. Please refer to this [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions013.htm#SQLRF52152).

The following query would return all the crew members who are NOT supervisors of any other crew member, without any errors. Additionally, the JOIN would perform very well.

```
SELECT
  CREWS.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM CREW
  )
  CREWS
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT CREW_SUPERVISOR_ID FROM CREW
  )
  SUPERVISORS
ON
  CREWS.CREW_ID = SUPERVISORS.CREW_SUPERVISOR_ID
WHERE
  SUPERVISORS.CREW_SUPERVISOR_ID IS NULL;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bbd18/1)</kbd>